# Is a value < or > the previous or following number?

Tags: r

I want to use R to generate a index column (i) for a datasheet based on how far each item is from the consecutive items immediately before it and after it:

1. if x is >10 from the previous value, but <10 from the next value, assign it "start"
2. if x is >10 from the previous value, and >10 from the next value, assign it "lone"
3. if x is <10 from the previous value, but >10 from the next value, assign it "end"
4. if x is <10 from the previous value, and <10 from the next value, assign it "middle"

For example, if the column named "x" read -
1,3,14,25,26,27,31,46....

The indexing column generated would read:
i = start,end,lone,start,middle,middle,end,start...

Does anyone know a good way of directing the "distance argument" of > or < 10, to only higher or lower values than itself?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. Even in your example, there are 8 items in your input and 6 in your output, and no hint of how you got from one to the other.

Comment: I tried editing your question since I think I understand it now (also see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` (which gets the distance between consecutive elements), along with `head` and `tail`:

```
before = head(diff(x), -1)
after = tail(diff(x), -1)
result = ifelse(before < 10, ifelse(after < 10, "start", "end"), ifelse(after < 10, "middle", "lone"))
```